# Athletic PG - Play Style

Tags: nba2k14

What could be the best play style as well as shot style for an athletic left handed point guard (6'4 195 pnds) in NBA 2K14 in order to increase his overall rating the fastest ?

Answer (score 0):

best play style is to upgrade defense, he will get tons of steals and blocks, also upgrade pass, assists get your grade up very quickly. after those, upgrade your 3 point shot and ball handling so he can ball with the 3 and go in for layups.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 things I'd upgrade are On-Ball Defense and 3 Point shooting, with a secondary recommendation to upgrade speed if you get a lot of points to spend. The reasoning is

- With high defense you don't lose as much teammate grade from bad defensive decisions and placement. You can basically spam the defensive help button and pay attention and you'll have serviceable to good D.
- With high shooting, you have the chance to score more points, which gets you the reward for scoring points. Also, your 3 pt rating doesn't have to be at 90 to be an almost automatic shooter. Getting it to 75 is good enough, 80 is better. The higher it is, the better chance of getting a "Good Shot Selection" off a 3, which you can get open by a calling a pick and running your man into it.
- With high speed, your player has the ability to simply run past slower players, especially after a screen. Getting your speed and quickness above 90, preferably 95, makes offense far easier.

After you play with your player for a while, you'll figure out which other skills you need to upgrade to make playing easier. Little things like passing, hands, shoot off dribble, awareness and stamina should probably be upgraded next.